# I want to add values to my picklist on the basis of a text field

Tags: picklist

I am having a text field and a picklist field.I want that picklist options be updated everytime a new & unique value is filled in the text field.So ,the next time user wishes to create a new record,he has that option available to be selected.How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you OK with the new text value not appearing in the picklist for the current instance of the page, but want it to appear the next time the page is displayed?

Comment: So you want to update the metadata from Apex? Check out this Apex wrapper for Metadata API https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: Yes @Keith that would be OK

Answer (score 1):

As AslamK mentions in his comment, you can modify the picklist entries from Apex. However, this is a web service call, and (I assume) requires permissions that typical users won't have. (Also, unless you cut it down the amount of Apex code you are adding is very large.)

An alternative is to merge the picklist values you get from a [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) describe call for the field with the added values obtained using a [group by](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) aggregate query on the field. Use a set to remove duplicates and then turn that set into a list and sort to have the values in a defined order. You return the values from your controller as a list of [SelectOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) objects and present them via the [apex:selectOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm) tag.

Also check that "Strictly enforce picklist values" is not selected for the picklist field.